# Passing image between views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitableview

I am solving this issue about 2 weeks and only be able to pass string, not image.

I store the image from camera or from library in this method.

```
-(IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{

    Tricks *trick = [[Tricks alloc]init];
    trick.trickName = self.trickLabel.text;
    trick.trickPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 356, 320, 305)];
    trick.trickPhoto.image = self.ImagePhoto.image;
    [[Tricks trickList]addObject:trick];
   }
```

In tableViewClass I store the values into properties of detailView

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailTrick"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController  = [segue destinationViewController];
        Tricks *trick = [[Tricks trickList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.trickPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 358, 200, 200)];
        detailViewController.fileText = trick.trickName;
        detailViewController.trickPhoto = trick.trickPhoto;
        //object = [Tricks trickList][indexPath.row]

    }
}
```

Text showed up every time without problems, but there is no image in detailViewController.Thanks for help.

viewDidLoad of detailViewController

```
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [self.detailButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_fileText] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.trickPhoto setImage:_trickPhoto.image];
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to get a grasp on what you mean to do: What does the Tricks class do? Is it meant to be a singleton? It looks like you're adding an instance of the Trick class to an array returned from a class method, which seams... odd.

Comment: static NSMutableArray *trickList = nil;

+(NSMutableArray *)trickList
{
    if(!trickList){
        trickList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
    }
    return trickList;
}

I am adding a cell to tableView, which represents a trick. In detailView there is a name and a picture

Comment: But your line [[Tricks trickList]addObject:trick]; returns and array with the trick object inside, but as no one is referencing it the array will be released as soon as you exit the method (immediately after that line). I assume you're using ARC...

Comment: Yes I am using ARC....so how do you suggest i pass the info??and text is passed without problems

Comment: iWasRobbed gives you a very nice example below of what is generally one of the most used patterns in Objective-C...

Comment: @JozefVrana Please make sure you close out old questions like these by hitting the checkmark symbol next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `trickPhoto` within the `Trick` class should be a `UIImage`, not a `UIImageView`. Models shouldn't know anything about views such as frames, etc so right now you're violating the MVC design pattern.

Then it'd be:

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender
{
    Tricks *trick = [[Tricks alloc] init];
    trick.trickName = self.trickLabel.text;
    trick.trickPhoto = self.ImagePhoto.image;
    [[Tricks trickList] addObject:trick];
}
```

The better way of doing this would be to create a `Trick` property within `DetailViewController` and just pass the whole trick into the view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailTrick"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController  = [segue destinationViewController];
        Tricks *trick = [[Tricks trickList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Make sure trick isn't nil: %@", trick);
        detailViewController.trick = trick;
    }
}
```

Then you'd just populate it with:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.detailButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.trick.trickName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.trickPhoto setImage:self.trick.trickPhoto];
```

Comment: You can imagine how thankful I am right now....you really helped me a lot. Problem before was, I was using UIImageView instead of UIImage

Comment: @JozefVrana Glad to help!  If this answered your question, please press the checkmark next to my answer to close out the question.